# How to use groupby with filter in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of students. ***How we can find count of students with only 1 successfully passed exam?*** Successfully passed - get 40 or more points.

Example table

```
student exam   score
123     Math   42
123     IT     39
321     Math   12
321     IT     11
333     IT     66
333     Math   77
```

For this example:

```
count of students = 1 #ans
student 123 has 1 succeeded passed exams
student 333 has 2 succeeded passed exams
student 321 0 exams passed
```

used `groupby()` but can't imagine `filter()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby("student")["score"].agg(lambda x: (x > 40).sum())
df_grouped[df_grouped == 1]
```

If you just want the count: just use `len(df_grouped[df_grouped == 1])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```py
out = (df['score'].ge(40)             # Is the score greater and equal than 40?
       .groupby(df['student']).sum()  # For each student, how many exams does he pass? (greater and equal than 40?)
       .eq(1).sum())                  # How many students only pass 1 exam?
```

```
print(out)

1
```

---

If you want to get the student id who only passes 1 exam

```py
out = (df['score'].ge(40)
       .groupby(df['student']).sum()
       .eq(1).loc[lambda s: s].index.tolist())
```

```
print(out)

[123]
```

---

If you want to find the student with his exam and score, you can use `groupby.filter`

```py
out = df.groupby('student').filter(lambda g: g['score'].ge(40).sum() == 1)
```

```
   student  exam  score
0      123  Math     42
1      123    IT     39
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data={
    "student":[123, 123, 321, 321, 333, 333],
    "exam":["Math", "IT", "Math", "IT", "IT", "Math"],
    "score":[42, 39, 12, 11, 66, 77],
}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

# groupby() student and count the number of exams with [score>=40]
num_passed_exams=df[df['score']>=40].groupby('student').size()

print(num_passed_exams)

res=len(num_passed_exams[num_passed_exams==1]) 

print("Student who passed at exactly one exam:",res)
```

**Output:**

```
student
123    1
333    2
dtype: int64
Student who passed at exactly one exam: 1
```